# Stripe Payment Link success link to include email

Tags: stripe-payments

I can't seem to figure out how to include email into stripe checkout success redirect.

I setup stripe check out payment link (from UI), simple subscription. Once payment is successful, I would like to redirect customer to my WebApp, but I do need to include customer's email.

[image]

Unfortunate redirect includes literal {CUSTOMER_EMAIL}, instead of real email. How can I mend it?

Answer (score 0):

CUSTOMER_EMAIL is not available. Only CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID. You can find how to use CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID to retrieve the Customer info from [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#create-success-page). But that would require you to write some code

```
get '/order/success' do
  session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.retrieve(params[:session_id])
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(session.customer)
```

Comment: Yeah, your approach requires call to stripe. I would like to avoid it, at least for basic data like customer email.